# Java code gives ORA-12514 error, yet I can connect via external program

Tags: java, oracle10g, database-connection

I have a test Java program that tries to connect to a database, but I have run into a weird situation.

Currently my code connects using let's say `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.20.30.40:1521/mydb`, with `user` and `password`.

I use an external program (Toad, in this case) to connect to `10.20.30.40` using the same values above, and I get a connection - well and good so far.

Now I change the connection string to connect to another database, say `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.20.30.50:1521/anotherdb`. I get the following SQLException:

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
//10.20.30.50:1521/anotherdb
```

However, when I try connecting using Toad, I manage to connect successfully.

How should I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection string needs to be

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.20.30.50:1521:anotherdb
```

You're using what's similar to MySQL's syntax and hence receiving the error.

---

When connecting to a database in Java (using JDBC) it's the JDBC driver provided by that database vendor that uses and determines the connection string format. Hence, they aren't portable between different databases.

Comment: But why does it work in the previous instance and not this current one? I don't understand

Comment: Toad is a pretty smart software. Usually we connect by filling up the details in the connection details input boxes. But if you were using the same connection string in Toad, I guess it must be parsing it to pull the details out of it.

Comment: So can I assume that the connection string you've provided in your answer is the "universal" format?

Comment: No, the format depends on the JDBC driver for the target database in use. Oracle has a different format. So, does MySQL and other databases. The one I've provided is what Oracle needs.